# Creating a Trigger for counting

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

how to create a trigger that will count a value of a single column in a row and compare the value with amount you put in. If the value exceeded the amount it will raise an error?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you maybe thinking of a check constraint.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but i want the trigger to fire when the limit of the single column in a single row exceeded or trying to insert more than the limit?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. And include your research and code.

Answer (score 0):

You need a check constraint, not a trigger. Look at this example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (colA INT)
ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT CK_value
    CHECK (colA <= 10)

--This works
INSERT INTO dbo.test
        ( colA )
VALUES  ( 1  -- colA - int
          )

--So does this
INSERT INTO dbo.test
        ( colA )
VALUES  ( 10  -- colA - int
          )

--This fails
INSERT INTO dbo.test
        ( colA )
VALUES  ( 101  -- colA - int
          )
```